# Generating IDs how to make IDs same length using zeroes?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

Update: The requirement is "fixed length 9 digits" so `460 000 000 138` should be `460 000 138`

I want to generate IDs on a special form such as `460 000 000 138` where 46 is the country code and the rest is the ID and this number always(?) has the same number of digits ie four pairs of threes.

My input is this ID that can be expected to be lower than some largest number. When starting the project from scratch the ID could be 1 and then just autoincrement as long as IDs don't collide (I probably would want a sequential count but that is tricky in distributed environment where actions can happen at the same time.

So input could be for example 138. I now want to fill with zeros and the country number, in this case Sweden (46) so the output should be 460 000 000 138

Similarly, if input is 1138 the output should be on the same form an fill with less zeroes ie 460 000 001 138

So I don't know how many zeroes I need. Can you help me? The solution should be in python. I will probably use the entity ID, fill with zeroes and add the country code and can you help me find an algorithm in python for that?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you asking about the string `format` method?  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting.  What part of this is confusing?  Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I'm looking at a solution with zfill. It can probably also be done with `format`

Comment: There's no *probably*.  It's generally done with `format`.  Indeed, it's done so frequently with `format`, that I'm confused as to why you're asking.  Did you try `format`?  What went wrong with `format`?

Comment: @S.Lott Thanks for the comment. I will try format and therefore must read python language manual which is boring compared to testing ready solutions ;-(.

Comment: "therefore must read python language manual".  Asking us to do work for you because you're too bored by the reference manual is actually insulting.  Glad you filled us in on that.

Comment: @S.Lott thanks for not even linking to a remotely related example.

Comment: "Asking us to do work for you because you're too bored by the reference manual is actually insulting."  It's my (possibly mistaken) impression that the `format` section is quite clear.  If it's not clear to you, it would help if you could ask something **specific** about `format` that would indicate what part is not clear.  I can't emphasize enough that asking us to do work for you because you're too bored by the reference manual is actually insulting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.zfill()` serves exactly this purpose.

```
>>> "1138".zfill(10)
0000001138
```

after that you just need to format the string to prepend the country code and then insert spaces wherever you require

Comment: Cool! zfill can do what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: I'll use this to make a function that generates the ID of fixed length 9 since that is the requirement.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: Sorry, I don't understand. If the ID needs to have a fixed length of 9, then you should not be using this answer; you should use the answer of benw, or the fixed total length expression in my answer, in each case replacing 12 by 9.

Comment: @John Machin I though just doing `zfill(9)` and the replacing the first digits with the country code. INHO fixed length of 9 will be too short for the environment since the ID the system generates typically are at least of length 7 even if there are nothing else in the group because GAE doesn't reuse IDs and IDs are unique for more than a group so I should be using fixed length of 12 and why not with zfill since it appears suitable just add the preceding countrycode and I'm good?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: First you say 12, then you say "ID of fixed length 9 since that is the requirement" and provide an example (460 000 138, where 46 is the countrycode), now you say that you "should be using fixed length of 12" and prepending the countrycode, which would give you a total length varying between 13 and 15. Make up your mind.

Comment: @John Machin Thanks for the comment and I'm sorry for changing the spec. I didn't ask for the requirement to change it's my decision-maker who latest said there should be 9 digits and the first 3 dedicated to country code so that makes me wonder how the ID part is generated if it's like an autoincrement then a distributed enviornment won't have it and I don't know the advantage of using this kind of ID to begin with, it's just to mimic another system maybe to make usernames neutral or after some standard I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

```
def makeid(countrycode, n):
    countrycode = str(countrycode)
    n = str(n)
    return "%s%s%s" % (countrycode, '0'*(12-len(countrycode)-len(n)), n)
```

Answer (score 1):

"always(?)" indeed. Sweden = 46 looks like you mean the telephone not-necessarily-a-country code which is VARIABLE LENGTH ... for example CHINA = 86, HONG KONG (not a country) = 852, CANADA = USA = 1. Is your ID allowed to be variable length or not?

If it is allowed to be variable, you would need do `str(countrycode) + str(n).zfill(10)` ... this allows `n` to be up to 10 digits.

Otherwise, for a fixed total length of 12 digits, you would need `str(countrycode) + str(n).zfill(12 - len(str(countrycode)))`

Comment: Yes I suspect it's the telephone code that is getting built into my ID type which makes me wonder what the advantage is doing that and I think I understand what you ean that it is not clear whether length is fixed or 11 or twelve parts.. Even worse, the system-generated ID:s (from GAE) might show not suitable for use as ID:s like these. Thank you very much for providing me the extra info.